# How to render write complex mathematics equations in nativescript-vue?

Tags: latex, nativescript, nativescript-vue

There is this plugin (https://github.com/zzish/react-latex#readme) that renders LaTex in React. Is there a way to use a similar plugin in NativeScript-Vue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, that is a React component and not a ReactNative component. That component is a wrapper to Katex, which renders LaTex to HTML.

A way to use it NativeScript-Vue is to render LaTex to html render it in a `<WebView>`, like so:

```
<template>
  ...
  <WebView :src="exprHtml" height="100"/>
  ...
</template>

<script>
  ...
  mounted() {
    this.exprHtml = katex.renderToString("c = \\pm\\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}", {
      throwOnError: false
    });
  } 
</script>
```

You can find a working playground example [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=1SJL6n).

Note that the `<WebView>` component is like a mini browser added inside your app. Don't add too many of them in a single screen.

Comment: I want to show may equation in a single page. Any other solution by which I can achiever this?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You can use this solution in a single page...